Adding accessibility for text elements
I am working on adding accessibility to a website.
Now I know that aria-labels, aria-labelledby, etc are meant to give accessible names to interactive type of elements as clearly mentioned in this blog. Hence, they may not work consistently with elements of type p, span, etc.
I want to do two things:

There is a text on the website "between 0-5m".

Currently the screen reader reads it as: "between zero five million"
I want it to be read as: "between zero and five million"
What I tried is the following:


.visually-hidden {
  position: 'absolute';
  height: '1px';
  width: '1px';
  padding: '0';
  margin: '-1px';
  overflow: 'hidden';
  border: '0';
}
0<span aria-hidden="true">-</span><span class="visually-hidden">and</span>5m



Now the screen reader reads it as: "between zero and five m".
Hence, this approach is clearly not working.

There are table headers in one of my table which are abbreviations: For example, table header is CAGR which is full form for Compounded Annual Growth Rate. Also to explain the meaning of these abbreviations the following thing has been done:

Table header is given as CAGR1 and then at the bottom after the table there is 1CAGR - definition of CAGR.
For accessibility I want that initially when table headers are read then table header along with its definition are read out and then as values are read out only the abbreviation is read.
Also, currently the screen reader reads CAGR as a word but instead I want it to be read as "C A G R".
Since above all are text elements using aria-labels will not work and using visually hidden text may cause other problems as shown above. What approach can I use to achieve these things to make the website more accessible?

Does this answer your question? How can I override a screen-reader's pronunciation of a word in a sentence without having it pause mid-sentence?. To sum it up: Don’t mess with how screen readers read stuff.

@andy the linked duplicate does not fit here. The linked question is about pronunciation of screen readers which is not the topic here. This topic is about abbreviations and how to solve them.

The result is the same. Don’t. There are many questions like this one that ask the same thing: How to make a screen reader read stuff differently. Unfortunately the generic question doesn’t exist, but it’s still duplicate and redundant.

The answer for this is not don't. There are specific tools for this very cases. The answer don't fits for pronunciation as that is not an issue. Things that a screen reader cant understand in the first place is a completely different topic

There is a lot to learn about Accessibility. A good starting point is WCAG 2.1.
However, you can also overdo Accessibility which then has a negative impact. Especially creating element that will be visually hidden have a very negative impact on your accessibility score. 
So be really careful with that. What you can do that works as you intend is the following technique:


<td>
  <span aria-label="between zero and five million"><span aria-hidden="true">0-5m</span></span>
</td>



Here you nest 2 spans inside each other. The inner span hides the content from the screen reader so that the outer span effectively will be empty to the screen reader. As such the aria-label value will then be read by screen readers. Screen readers will only read the aria-label if the element has no content for the screen reader itself. That way you do not visually hide content but still can read the intended text correctly.
Note that m in itself is not accessible as well. m would normally refer to meter and not millions. In any case, abbreviations such as GB (which could be Gigabyte or Great Britain) as well as Mo. 1st Oct.. are not accessible at all and should always written out completely! Most importantly accessibility guidelines require you to have text to be easily understandable. This also means to not name links such as click here but to give them a meaningful description such as read more about...
In the specific case of CAGR the same rules as above apply. As such you should not create a term for the screen reader to read it out as C.A.G.R. (note that you use dots to create pauses between the letters for screen readers) but you can use the <abbr> tag for that specific case that exactly exists for such cases:


<abbr title="Compounded Annual Growth Rate">CAGR</abbr>



The abbreviation is written within the text while you use the title attribute for the screen reader to read out the actual meaning of the abbreviation.
Last but not least the golden WCAG rule is:

Wrongly placed aria-attributes are worse than no aria-attributes

As such remember not to overdo it and if you're not sure if an aria-attribute would fit in a case then either ask or don't use it at all.
Reference material to learn more about accessibility:
WAI-ARIA - Bad Practises

HTML Accessibility Guide of the Penn State University

Also describedby can be useful for abbreviations or acronyms - you can link the acronym to a footnote.

agreed but I would use that only in cases where you actually show it to all users not exclusively to screen readers. IMHO that case abbr is the better choice. Otherwise, you would treat the users and screen readers differently.

Not if you do not hide the footnote

This cleared a lot of my queries. Just one query remains. For the table I want table header definition to be read out initially but when values are read only the table header should be read and not the complete definition is that possible? Currently it keeps on repeating the definition.

honestly, that is not something you should change IMHO. Screen reader users run the screen reader at incredible speed. Much faster than a normal person reads. It is not an issue for them. I wouldn't bother too much unless they specifically complain about it.

Oh I understand. The only thing is the definition is a quite long sentence and some testers have asked if this would be possible to achieve.

@mplungjan you mentioned about linking the abbreviations to definitions in footnote using describedby. So, when I do this is it expected that the content linked using it is automatically read by screen reader or some extra actions needs to be done for it?

@tacoshy I also tried abbr for CAGR. The screen does seems to read the definition though. Only difference is now when I hover the mouse over the abbreviation it shows the definition. Although, I think that is because of the title attribute.

@DhruvDeshmukh https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-describedby

For both questions, probably you shouldn't do anything special for screen readers, and leave it presented as it is, unless you receive specific complains about it.
In general, it's quite a bad idea to replace a text by another text specifically for screen readers.
Here are several reasons for that:

The way numbers, symbols, units are read vary a lot depending on the operating system, browser, screen reader, voice used and their specific settings. You can't test all possible combinations.
That's the same for abbreviations like CAGR for which you can't control if it should be read as a word or spelled out.
So by making a change, you may well improve accessibility for a minority while  make it worse for the majority.
Braille users will probably much better and much quicklyy understand "0-5M" than "between 0 and 5 millions", and same for "CAGR", as they are used to read such abbreviations as sighted users are
In tables specifically, keep in mind that header cells can be repeated many times as you are reading through the table. A long header repeated a lot can become annoying.
Also, braille users can have header cells kept on the same line as the cell content for easier reading, but space is very limited (40 characters and often less). With your longer label, you may prevent from using that quite useful feature.
Blind people aren't alone to use screen readers, they are also used by people with dyslexia or other troubles. If what's on the screen doesn't match what's read, you may increase cognitive load for the people who already have difficulties.
Abbreviations like "5m" aren't standardized. They may be read as "5 millions", "5 minutes" or "5 meters" for example, but you shouldn't worry so much about it. Screen reader user doesn't mean totally stupid person, so what you mean will probably be correctly understood. Screen reader users are used to pronounciation quirks like that. They even laugh about it, and perfectly understand.

By the way, maybe that the visually hidden technique doesn't work in your particular case (your first question), but in general it works quite well.
I don't see any issue using them in table headers for example, if despite the above arguments, you still want to do it. Watch out spacing, though, as unwanted words can be read glued together.
A note about the abbreviation "5m". You have certainly greater changes to have it read "5 millions" by using a capital M.
The lowercase m is generally rather used for meters, or sometimes for minutes.
If you are talking about money, it would also better to add the money symbol, for example "5M$". It will definitively remove the doubt that it might be meters or minutes, for screen reader users as well as for all users.

I understand and that's why most of the site has not been modified, there were only these minor changes. The currency symbol is present and I think that's why it is able to pick the context and say 5m as 5 million correctly.  Your third point is quite important to me. Is there a way we can prevent it? I mean the definition is read out only initially and later only the abbreviation is read.

As far as I know, no, using techniques shown in the other answer, there is no way to make it read in full the first time, and then abbreviated. That's always or never, but it's understandable why it's so: it can create onfusion if something isn't read twice the same; and when should the full version should be repeated again ? each time you enter the table ? only once per page load ? and if I missed the full version and want it repeated ? So this isn't so simple to implement on the screen reader side, for what it's worth.
